# How to distinguish objects that inherits QGraphicsItems when stored on QGraphicsScene.selectedItems()

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, multiple-inheritance

Here is the situation:

1. There are two classess that inherits both `QGraphicsItem` and `QObject` - `Car` and `Bike`.
2. There are several objects of each class visualized using `QGraphicsScene myScene`.
3. At some point two of the objects are selected and are available via `myScene.selectedItems()`
4. There are different behaviour defined for interaction `Car - Car`,`Bike - Bike`, `Bike - Car`.

Since `QGraphicsItem` does not inherits from `QObject` I cannot invoke `metaObject()->className()` on item during:

```
foreach(QGraphicsItem* item,this->scene.selectedItems())
{
    item->metaObject()->className(); --error 'class QGraphicsItem' has no member named 'metaObject'
}
```

It is possible to use `QGraphicsItem::data` but it requires setting performing `setData(...)` it when creating objects.

Q:Is there any way to get an information what kind of objects are present  on `selectedItems` list (ideally using `className()`) so the correct interaction function will be used?

Comment: Why "setData(...)" is not a viable option? Alternatively you can try dynamic_casts. Also you cannot use the metaObject information, because "item" is of QGraphicsItem type, but since your classes inherit also from QObject, it should be safe to cast item to QObject* and use information stored there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Losiowaty said, you can use dynamic_cast.

Example:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem*> g_items = scene->selectedItems();
for(int i = 0; i < g_items.length(); i++)
{
    QObject *selected_object = dynamic_cast<QObject*>(g_items[i]);
    if(selected_object)
    {
        //do what you need to do
    }
}
```

You can also cast your selected items directly to your `Car` or `Bike` class.

Comment: That requires building Qt with RTTI which means a lot of cruft for a trivial use case.

Comment: That doesn't perform any checks if it's actually of the type you want.

Comment: @Trass3r Yeah. I don't know what I was thinking there.

Answer (score 3):

The Qt solution for that (which also works in the -no-rtti case) is to use qgraphicsitem_cast and [implement type()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsitem.html#UserType-var):

```
class CustomItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
   ...
   enum { Type = UserType + 1 };

   int type() const
   {
       // Enable the use of qgraphicsitem_cast with this item.
       return Type;
   }
   ...
};
```